# battery drain AFTER kitkat update

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, samsung-galaxy-s-5

On Samsung S5 AFTER installing KitKat last week, the mm-qcamera deamon usage has drain down full battery in 7hours (before update 12+ hours uptime was the average.
Hopefully an urgent fix is coming. So far the key argument for me for Android was the lack or quick fix of bugs...

Comment: I can't seem to find a question here. Can you elaborate or edit?

Comment: Lack of a question mark doesn't change the obvious: Rapid battery drain is not a positive thing, so how can it be fixed?

Comment: @MatthewRead Fair Enough. I'll find something.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report that has been filed to AOSP about this with a FutureRelease status (a bug fix will be coming soon). Read it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60058).

> It seems that a **reboot** provides a temporary fix for the problem.
>   A **factory reset** fixed the issue permanently for most users.